# How to retrieve Date and Time from SOAP Response?

Tags: java, soap

I am getting proper SOAP response from the endpoint, but how can I get the date and time from SOAP Response by when the service was hit?

```
soapRequest = createSoapMessage(wsRequestString);
soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
soapConnection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();
URL endPoint = new URL(URL);
soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequest, endPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done via HTTP headers. In Java you can o something like this.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

String getURL = "your_url";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
String DateTime = responseGet.getHeaders("Date");
```

You can chage the top 3 lines as per your requirements.

Comment: I got the answer after few trials, you can see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

---

### Prints the Date and Time of the SOAP Response

```
soapRequest = createSoapMessage(wsRequestString);
soapConnFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
soapConnection = soapConnFactory.createConnection();
URL endPoint = new URL(URL);
soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequest, endPoint);
String[] str = soapResponse.getMimeHeaders().getHeader("Date");
System.out.println(str[0]);
```